# Ctrl + alt + f8 takes monitor down

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I've used a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f8</kbd> shortcut in my Linux VM hosted on Windows 10. Unfortunately the moment I've pressed this buttons my second screen turned black and started displaying "Cannot Display This Video Mode".

I've updated my video card drivers (i have a dedicated one) and tried to change a resolution and framerate but with no result.

I've disabled a service and killed process as written here: [Ctrl Alt F8 disconnects displays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108927/ctrl-alt-f8-disconnects-displays), but also with no effect.

I don't know what to do - service is disabled but screen is still black and changing resolution or switching between multiple displays modes does nothing. Thanks in advance for answer or a hint.

EDIT:

I'm sorry i forgot to mention - i've one monitor plugged into graphics card and second which stopped working is plugged into motherboard (Gigabyte Z270-HD3P) because my graphics card doesn't have a VGA port. Earlier they have been both working in this configuration for months.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you rebooted the PC? System restore (not factory reset)?

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply. I've rebooted the PC many times and nothing. I've also tried turning off and on internal graphics in BIOS (I'm sorry i forgot to mention - i've one monitor plugged into graphics card and second which stopped working is plugged into motherboard (Gigabyte Z270-HD3P) because my graphics card doesn't have a VGA port). Unfortunately i've had system protection disabled and there isn't any restore points

Comment: I've fixed similar things by looking in the system tray and looking in the Intel Graphics controls.  I don't have an example machine on hand, so I can't take a screenshot.

Comment: Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108927/ctrl-alt-f8-disconnects-displays

Comment: Thanks a lot - changing resolution in Intel Graphics controls helped.

Answer (score 1):

just posting the answer here for posterity.

CTRL+ALT+F8 goes to the standard console/terminal which is what lies behind when you have X running. TTY8, which usually doesn't have anything running, is therefore blank - sometimes with a blinking cursor in top left corner.

If you hit CTRL+ALT+F7, you should be back in X, which is usually the "TTY" where X is at.

When you're in any TTY, the CTRL+ALT shortcut can also be accessed just with ALT, e.g. ALT+1 takes you to TTY1. You can also hold ALT and use LEFT/RIGHT arrow keys to go quickly to left/right TTY.